# When is function in Lp

Tags: analysis

It is

$u\in L^p(U) \Leftrightarrow \int_u |u(x)|^p dx < \infty$

I tried to investigate for which parameters $\alpha>0, n\in \mathbb{N}, 1\leq p < \infty$ the function $u(x) = |x|^{-\alpha} , x\in U=B(0,1), x\neq 0$ is in $L^p(U)$. $B(0,1)$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I looked at

$\int_U ||x|^{-\alpha}|^p dx $

and computed the derivative

$ \partial_iu(x) = -\alpha x_i |x|^{-\alpha -2}$

But actually I don´t see what to use to show that the integral is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not need any derivative. Instead, you need to use polar coordinates as shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389555/integration-of-radial-functions). More precisely,
$$
\int_U |x|^{-p\alpha} \, dx = \omega_{N-1} \int_0^{1} r^{-p\alpha} r^{N-1}\, dr = \omega_{N-1} \int_0^{1} r^{N-1-p\alpha}\, dr.
$$
Here $\omega_{N-1}$ is a positive constant, the surface area of the unit sphere in dimension $N$.
I am pretty sure that now you can investigate for what values of $p$ the last 1D-integral exists.

Comment: I found that the integral exists for all $\alpha \neq \frac{n}{p}$.

Comment: One more question: The gradient of $u$ is $\nabla u(x) = -\alpha x |x|^{-\alpha -2}$, so when I would like to investigate when this function is in $L^p$ I have the integral $\int_U \alpha^p |x|^p |x|^{-\alpha p -2p}$. How can I apply polarcoordinates here?

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition from Folland's Real Analysis:

If $(X, M, \mu)$ is a measure space, then, for $0 < p < \infty$, then

$L^p(X, M, \mu) = \left\{f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}| f \text{ is measurable and } \|f\|_p < \infty\right\}$,

where

$\|f\|_p = \left(\int |f|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

So I think you were missing the $1/p$ power of the integral.

Comment: It is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: Ah yeah I see that now. I thought he was asking about the definition.