# Is $1/(1+|y|^k)$ in $L^2(R^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Is $1/(1+|y|^k)$ in $L^2(R^n)$ for $k>n/2$?

My attempt. Wondering if someone could verify this:

$\int_{R^n} \frac1{{(1+|y|^k})^2}=\int_0^\infty \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r^k)^2}dr$ (Using polar coordinates)
$\leq \int_0^\infty \frac{r^{n-1}}{r^{2k}}=\int_0^\infty r^{n-1-2k}$ So if $0>n-2k$ this would diverge and I havent gained any information correct?  Any hints on how to do this

Answer (score 2):

The equality you got from changing to polar coordinates is not correct. There would be  a constant factor on RHS. But this does not affect integrability.

For $k <0$ it is easy to see that the function is not integrable. Let $k \geq 0$. Then integrability neat $0$ is clear. So we only have to consider finiteness of $\int_1^{\infty} \frac {r^{n-1}} {(1+r^{k})^{2}}dr$. Comparing with $\int_1^{\infty} \frac {r^{n-1}} {(r^{k})^{2}}dr$ we see that  the condition is $n  <2k$.

Comment: Can you explain how the integrability near $0$ is clear. Sorry, Im not seeing it

Comment: For $k \geq 0$ just observe that $1+r^{k} \geq 1$ and $r^{n-1}$ is integrable near $0$.

Comment: @sassh By the way [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389555/) for the constant mentioned by Kavi