# How to show function raised to $-\alpha$ is in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ when $p\alpha < d$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $|x|=(x_1^2 + \ldots + x_d^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Let $f_u(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$ if $|x| <1$, $f_u(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq1$.

Let $f_k(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$ if $|x| \geq 1$, $f_k(x)=0$ for $|x| <1$.

Show that:

(1) $f_u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ iff $p \alpha < d$ and

(2) $f_k \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ iff $d < p \alpha$.

---

My attempt:

I think what I need to do in order to show that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)| < \infty.$

So $f_u(x) = (x_1^p + \ldots + x_d^p)^{1/{p\alpha}}$.

Since $p\alpha<d$, $p/d < 1/\alpha$.

Then $(x_1^p + \ldots + x_d^p)^{1/{p\alpha}} > (x_1^p + \ldots + x_d^p)^{1/{d}}$

... not sure what now.

Comment: Hint: Use the well known formula for integrate radial functions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389555/integration-of-radial-functions

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser, is it better now?

Comment: @AlyxLogins Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that we can integrate radial functions as
$$\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(|x|)\mathrm d^n x=A_{n-1}\int_0^\infty f(r)r^{n-1}\mathrm dr$$

With
$$A_{n}=\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}$$

Hence
$$\int_{\Bbb R^n}f_u(x)\mathrm d^n x=A_{n-1}\int_0^1 r^{-\alpha}r^{n-1}\mathrm dr \\ \int_{\Bbb R^n}f_k(x)\mathrm d^nx=A_{n-1}\int_1^\infty r^{-\alpha}r^{n-1}\mathrm dr$$
Can you proceed?