# How does one relate $\int_{ \mathbb{R}^{d} }f( \left\| x\right\|_{ } ) \,\mathrm{d}x $ to a one dimensional integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

I remember that I saw such a relationship at some point but don't recall how the result was called. Intuitively one would expect to be able to get a one dimensional integral and some correction factor proportional to the unit ball. Could someone point me to the desired theorem?

Comment: You can use polar coordinates. The factor will be the volume of the unit Euclidean sphere of f R^{d} : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389555/integration-of-radial-functions

Comment: @jvc I think you get the measure of the sphere and not the ball.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it.

Comment: @jvc Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(\lVert x \rVert)~\mathrm{d}x = \int^\infty_0 \int_{\partial B_r(0)} f(\lVert x \rVert) ~\mathrm{d}S(x)~\mathrm{d}r$

Answer (score 6):

If $ C_n$ is the area of the sphere $\{x\in \mathbb R^n; \|x\|=1\}$ then your integral is $C_n\int_0^{\infty}f(r)r^{n-1}dr.$